# Bind the `this` scope of a promise callback function

Tags: javascript

Normally if you aren't using promises you can easily do

```
var a = function(cb){
  setTimeout(function(){
    var boundCb = cb.bind({hello: 'world'});
    boundCb();
  }, 100);
};

a(function(){
  alert(this.hello);
});
```

which isn't particularly useful most of the times (as you can pass the same things as normal arguments), but it does allow for some extremely readable code and/or simple to use interfaces.

When switching to promises however it suddenly becomes a lot harder to do. Unsurprisingly the following **doesn't** work (as `resolve` isn't a direct reference)

```
var a = function(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var boundResolve = resolve.bind({hello: 'word'});
    boundResolve();
  });
};

a().then(function(){
  alert(this.hello)
});
```

so is there any way at all to achieve this?

---

Non essential postscriptum: 'Luckily' in my situation the `this` scope I want to set is already the same as what the `this` scope is at `a()`. So I am currently simply writing `.bind(this)` after every single Promise callback function and in the future I will be able to use arrow functions for this, but I am looking for a cleaner solution in the interim.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very good idea to me. You want to associate a promise with some `this` value when you create it, and then in some completely separate place refer to that value with `this`? Seems like a real head-scratcher for anyone maintaining your code as it breaks the [Principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: @JLRishe: From an API consumption point it can make a lot of sense though, but you would have to look at the broader context of the specific case to understand. (Polymer elements where `this` is by-design supposed to always refer to the current element.)

Answer (score 4):

Native Promises do not offer this functionality. However, the Bluebird Promise library offers **[Promise.prototype.bind](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.bind.html)**

Here's an example usage

```
MyClass.prototype.method = function() {
    return fs.readFileAsync(this.file).bind(this)
    .then(function(contents) {
        var url = urlParse(contents);
        return this.httpGetAsync(url); // this is bound to the MyClass instance
    }).then(function(result) {
        // this is still bound, further down the chain.
        var refined = this.refine(result); 
        return this.writeRefinedAsync(refined);
    }).catch(function(e) {
        this.error(e.stack); // Even in event handlers
    });
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I feared so@"Native Promises do not offer this functionality.". Didn't want to rush to conclusions though before first checking :) . Really wouldn't mind if they added that to the API, would be useful in a lot of ways.

Comment: Promise callbacks are designed with statelessness in mind. `this` implies state, which is not the "clean way".

Comment: Not trying to give them any state (as I want to `bind` the broader `this` scope 'back'), but totally get what you're saying.

Comment: In that case, use lamda expressions. They will automatically bind your `this` to the caller's `this`.

Comment: > "and in the future I will be able to use arrow functions for this, but I am looking for a cleaner solution in the interim."

So I totally agree with you ;-)